# Determinant of matrix similar to Vandermonde determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find a closed form for the following determinant:
[image]

I have tried solving it similar to the normal Vandermonde determinant but when you multiply $1+a_1$ by $a_1$ there appears an extra $a_1$ that destroyes this idea

Comment: It is just the matrix with all etries equal to $1$ plus a Vandermonde. It was posted here recently.

Comment: Without the $1$'s it is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007360/how-to-evaluate-the-determinant-of-this-matrix). Let me look for the duplicate.

Comment: I know, but the added 1's make it much different

Comment: Different yes, but there was a nice argument how to compute the determinant of the sum of these two matrices. Some trick like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009952/cute-problem-determinant-of-i-nf-if-j-i-j?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$D_n = \begin{vmatrix}
1+a_1 & 1+ a_1^2 & \cdots & 1+a_1^n\\
1+a_2 & 1+ a_2^2 & \cdots & 1+a_2^n\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
1+a_n & 1+ a_n^2 & \cdots & 1+a_n^n
\end{vmatrix}$$

We begin by substracting the $n-1$-th column to the $n$-th, then the $n-2$-th to the $n-1$-th, then the $n-3$-th to the $n-2$-th, and so on, until substracting the first column to the second. This gives
$$D_n = \begin{vmatrix}
1+a_1 & a_1(a_1-1) & \cdots& a_1^{n-2}(a_1-1) & a_1^{n-1}(a_1-1)\\
1+a_2 & a_2(a_2-1) & \cdots& a_2^{n-2}(a_2-1) & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-1)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
1+a_n & a_n(a_n-1) & \cdots& a_n^{n-2}(a_n-1) & a_n^{n-1}(a_n-1)
\end{vmatrix}$$
So you get
$$D_n = \begin{vmatrix}
2+(a_1-1) & a_1(a_1-1) & \cdots& a_1^{n-2}(a_1-1) & a_1^{n-1}(a_1-1)\\
2+(a_2-1) & a_2(a_2-1) & \cdots& a_2^{n-2}(a_2-1) & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-1)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
2+(a_n-1) & a_n(a_n-1) & \cdots& a_n^{n-2}(a_n-1) & a_n^{n-1}(a_n-1)
\end{vmatrix} = A_n + B_n$$

where
$$A_n = \begin{vmatrix}
2 & a_1(a_1-1) & \cdots& a_1^{n-2}(a_1-1) & a_1^{n-1}(a_1-1)\\
2 & a_2(a_2-1) & \cdots& a_2^{n-2}(a_2-1) & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-1)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
2 & a_n(a_n-1) & \cdots& a_n^{n-2}(a_n-1) & a_n^{n-1}(a_n-1)
\end{vmatrix}$$ $$\text{and} \quad B_n = \begin{vmatrix}
a_1-1 & a_1(a_1-1) & \cdots& a_1^{n-2}(a_1-1) & a_1^{n-1}(a_1-1)\\
a_2-1 & a_2(a_2-1) & \cdots& a_2^{n-2}(a_2-1) & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-1)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
a_n-1 & a_n(a_n-1) & \cdots& a_n^{n-2}(a_n-1) & a_n^{n-1}(a_n-1)
\end{vmatrix} =  V(a_1, ..., a_n)\prod_{k=1}^n (a_k-1)$$

(where $V(a_1, ..., a_n)$ is the classical Vandermonde determinant)

It remains to determine $A_n$. By developping the determinant along the first column, one has
$$A_n = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} V(a_1, ..., \widehat{a_i}, ..., a_n)\prod_{k=1 \\ k \neq i}^n a_k(a_k-1)$$

where $V(a_1, ..., \widehat{a_i}, ..., a_n)$ denotes the Vandermonde determinant of the family $\lbrace a_1, ..., a_n \rbrace \setminus \lbrace a_i \rbrace$.

All put together, you get that
$$\boxed{D_n = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} V(a_1, ..., \widehat{a_i}, ..., a_n)\prod_{k=1 \\ k \neq i}^n a_k(a_k-1) + V(a_1, ..., a_n)\prod_{k=1}^n (a_k-1)}$$

which can (possibly) be simplified further.

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution.